# SQL Server Incorrect Syntax

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

I keep getting the error listed below:

Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Procedure spGetManagerName, Line 22
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'SELECT'.

Situation:
A user selects (from a dropdown) a team which converts to a teamID and is sent to the data access layer (DAL).  The teamID is passed into the stored procedure.  Based on the teamID... the team & the manager table are quizzed to divulge the correct managers name.

The problem:
I keep getting a syntax error message.  I know/think its something small but just can't see it.

Anybody see what's going on with this...

```
USE [Travel_Test]
GO

SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO


-- =============================================

-- Description: Getting Manager Name via Team dropdown selection
-- =============================================
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[spGetManagerName]
@inputTeamID int,
@ManName nvarchar(50) OUTPUT    
AS
-- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
-- interfering with SELECT statements.

SET NOCOUNT ON;
SELECT 
    @ManName = ManagerFName + ' ' + ManagerLName AS ManagerName
FROM 
    Managers m
WHERE
    m.ManagerID = SELECT
                        Team.ManagerID
                   FROM
                        Team
                   WHERE
                        Team.TeamID = @inputTeamID;
                   RETURN

GO
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to add parenthesis to the subquery:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[spGetManagerName]
@inputTeamID int,
@ManName nvarchar(50) OUTPUT    
AS
-- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
-- interfering with SELECT statements.

SET NOCOUNT ON;
SELECT 
    @ManName = ManagerFName + ' ' + ManagerLName 
FROM 
    Managers m
WHERE
    m.ManagerID = (SELECT
                        Team.ManagerID
                   FROM
                        Team
                   WHERE
                        Team.TeamID = @inputTeamID
                   );
RETURN
GO
```

Comment: I think you should remove the alias "AS ManagerName" in the first select

Comment: Looks like I had to do both to get it to work add the paraenthesis and remove a (+ ' ' + ManagerLName AS ManagerName).... however I need both first and last name.  I tried just removing alias but that didn't work.  Any way I can get both first and last name.  I have a sp I was using to load  a managers dropdown that worked fine:

Comment: I have upvoted your answer. But IMO, It will fail if the inner subquery returns more than 1 id. (Though in real life it is an unlikely event). But for the sake of sanity, you should probably replace `=` with an `IN`

Comment: @Sourav_Agasti Thank you for your upvote and you opinion! I completely agree with you. I was thinking about `=` and `in`. It was very close to change the operator to `in`. I didn't change it because I don't know data stored in `Team` table, I hope `TeamID` is `PK` an subquery return only one row.

Comment: My top 1 with a join deals with 1 or more

Answer (score 0):

```
Select Top 1 @ManName = m.ManagerFName + ' ' + m.ManagerLName 
  FROM Managers m
  JOIN Team 
    ON m.ManagerID = Team.ManagerID
   AND Team.TeamID = @inputTeamID;
```

Comment: Then try without AS ManagerName

Comment: I thought I had tried that... must not have.  It worked using the parenthesis and by removing "AS ManagerName"  Thanks folks